# Is it possible to make WebStorm+Meteor.js hot code pushes faster?

Tags: meteor, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am working with WebStorm 2016.1.3 on Win7 and Meteor.js 1.3.

Every time I change anything in my code in WebStorm, the changes do not apply in the browser as long as I keep the WebStorm window in the foreground.
It seems like I need to leave the WebStrom window and bring it to the background or focus any other window, to make WebStorm perform the changes. Because only then the browser becomes aware of the changes and it starts applying them.

Is it possible to make the changes apply on the run? Changes in a simple HTML file that is edited in a non Meteor project in WebStorm, are applied with LiveEdit on the run. They are usually applied even before I can switch to the browser. But how do I achieve this in a meteor project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try saving manually (`ctrl` + `s` on Windows).

Meteor rebuilds your project when it detects a file change. But JetBrains IDEs don't save the file on every keystroke. Changes are saved when you leave the PhpStorm window, that's why you see your changes then.

Comment: that makes sense and it works. Well will have to push 'ctrl + s' all the time from now on ... :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Meteor but take a look in [this section](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/using-meteor.html#d264588e1422) maybe it is what are you looking for.

Comment: Generally this is not an answer, but a comment. Your not explaining anything other than referring to a link.

Comment: "The client-side code can be updated through the native Meteor hot code pushes functionality. The functionality is enabled by default, to activate it:
..." ----  I know that it is activated by default, and it is and it works. But that is not the question. The question is if I can make the hot code pushes execute instantly. Right now they are executed only if I leave the WebStorm window.

Comment: @dbf I can't post comments before because my reputation...but now I can. I'll use it from now on ;)

Comment: @henk I understand, I thought maybe something was not activated properly. As I said, I do not use Meteor so I don't know how it works...was just trying to help. ;)